# How can I transform translations to perserve magnitude in another space?

Tags: geometry

I am creating a videogame that is played on a grid of tiles like the red parallelogram in the image below.

[image]

There are two cartesian spaces here. First, the two dimensional space of the screen (screen space) whose axes are shown in green and labelled $x'$ and $y'$. Then there is the two dimensional game space whose axes are shown in black and labelled $x$, $y$. An important piece of geometry is that the red shape is a unit square in game space but, in screen space, is twice as wide as tall.

Say that an object is moves through game space with a translation of $(1,1)$; it moves through screen space with a translation of $(0, 1)$. Alternatively, if the object moves through game space with a translation of $(1,-1)$ it moves through screen space with a translation of $(2,0)$. As we can see from these examples, two translations with the same magnitude in game space don't necessarily have the same magnitude in screen space.

This is a problem for me since the apparent speed of an object (when viewed in screen space) changes depending on the direction of travel. This brings me to my question: **How can I transform a translation in game space such that two translations in game space with equal magnitude give two transformed translations of equal magnitude in screen space while not changing the direction of the translation**. That is, what is the function of a translation $f(t)$ that returns a translation such that, $$\forall t\cdot \frac{t}{|t|}=\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|} \land |t_1|=|t_2| \Rightarrow |g(f(t_1))||=|g(f(t_2))|$$ where $$g(x,y) = (x-y, \frac{x+y}{2})$$ is the function for translating game space coordinates to screen space coordinates.

The rest of this question is my working on this problem so far.

Initially it would seems that $f=g^{-1}$ since this trivially satisfies the second part, however $g^{-1}$ changes the direction of the translation and so doesn't satisfy the first part.

The first restriction on $f$ can be expressed as $f(t)=[t_x\times f'(t),t_y\times f'(t)]$ for some $f'(t)$ where $f'(t)$ has no such restriction.

Substituting this into the second part gives the following pair of equations.

$$t_{1x}^2+t_{1y}^2=t_{2x}^2+t_{2y}^2$$

$$f'(t_1)^2[5t_{1x}^2-6t_{1x}t_{1y}+5t_{1y}^2]=f'(t_2)^2[5t_{2x}^2-6t_{2x}t_{2y}+5t_{2y}^2]$$

I don't see how to arrange this to a closed form for $f'(t)$ (which would give us a closed form for $f(t)$ which is the objective). I feel there is something missing here. In particular, it would seem that trigonometric functions should be involved here due to the needed change in magnitude for the original translation changing sinusoidally as the original translation follows the unit circle in game space.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the game space is a Cartesian space projected onto the screen, then things **should** move more slowly in the screen's x direction than in the y direction. After all, if you're looking at a plane from far away at an angle, that's how it will look. If the game space actually lies in the plane of the screen, those coordinates are not Cartesian. Either way, what you're asking to do makes no sense. It's also impossible, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @DavidK I want to do this since it looks weird that your apparent speed changes depending on your direction as I stated in the post. I don't care about how the object "should" move since this is not supposed to be accurate simulation. My question here is not whether this is a good game design decision since, if it was, I would have asked elsewhere. What I have presented is a mathematical problem, why I want to solve it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: @DavidK what do you mean by impossible? That there is no closed form solution? There clearly is some solution since I can plot the desired function by sampling from it which shows that it exists.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the help, found the solution

Comment: The "why" really does matter because without it, it's unclear what you're doing. I suspect that your game space coordinates really are **not** Cartesian (axes must be perpendicular in Cartesian coordinates) and that this is what makes the problem seem impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f'(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{{(x-y)}^2+{(\frac{x+y}{2})}^2}}$$

Substitution into the second equation gives

$${(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{{(x-y)}^2+{(\frac{x+y}{2})}^2}})}^2[5x^2-6xy+5y^2]=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2)$$

And clearly

$$x_1^2+y_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2\Rightarrow \frac{1}{4}(x_1^2+y_1^2)=\frac{1}{4}(x_2^2+y_2^2)$$